# How to route audio from bluetooth headset's mic to android speakers

Tags: audio, bluetooth-audio, vanilla-android, android-tv, android-pc

I have an android app which routes mic audio to speakers in realtime. What I want it to do is instead of routing built in mic audio, it route audio from mic of a bluetooth headset.
Background: I just wanna use my bluetooth headset as mic and connect the phone to loud speakers so that whatever I speak comes through loud speakers wirelessly.

Comment: Old question, what app was this?